# How can I set comparison datetime in validation laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, datetime, laravel-5.3, required

I use laravel 5.3

My laravel validation like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class AddCartRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id'=>'required|numeric',
            ...
            'request_date'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

If value of request_date is

> 01-08-2017 13:00:00

I want to add condition like this :

If request date < now + 5 hour, then it will display message : "Request date must be larger 5 hours from now"

How can I do it?

Comment: You most likely need to write a custom validation rule.

Comment: @fubar, How to? You try to answer with the code. In my opinion it just needs to be added here: `'request_date'=>'required|...'`

But I am confused to add it

Comment: [Custom validation rules docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules). You try first and come back when you have questions.

Comment: Try using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). It is a very powerfull extension for DateTime..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can use `after:date`

> The field under validation must be a value after a given date. The
>   dates will be passed into the PHP  strtotime function.

You simply need to create the right date string using something like this:

```
'request_date'=>'after:'.date(DATE_ATOM, time() + (5 * 60 * 60)),
```

Seems that you can also chain these rules like this:

```
'request_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after:5 hours'
```

Comment: Surely you need to use the `request_date` value, rather than the current time?

Comment: He asked for '< now + 5 hour'.  It's a validation of an entered date.  This validation will fail, if the entered date is not at least 5 hours from now.  This is what is being asked for.

Comment: @gview, I try this : `'request_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after:5 hours'`, it works

Comment: still valid for laravel 5.7